# How take a merged branch out of a master branch (Github)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, git, git-branch

I worked on a branch in my Rails app, committed, and merged it into my master, because I was happy with everything, but now I want to take out that branch again and discard those changes.

Is it possible or too late now that I have merged the branch with the master?

Thanks

Comment: I pushed the merge to Github as well. Not just locally? Will git reset --hard commit_sha still work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have pushed commits to a central location, it's best not to modify them in any way.

An alternative is to generate a reverse commit.  That is, a commit that undoes all the changes in a previous commit.  One way is [`git-revert`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-revert.html).  Assuming that you've merged in commits `<sha2>`, `<sha3>` and `<sha4>`, you could:

```
git revert <sha4>
git revert <sha3>
git revert <sha2>
```

If you'd like to revert all changes in a single commit, try the `--no-commit` option:

```
git revert --no-commit <sha4>
git revert --no-commit <sha3>
git revert --no-commit <sha2>
git commit -m "Undid feature merge"
```

Another way to generate a single reverse commit is [`git checkout`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-checkout.html):

```
git checkout -f <sha2>
git commit -a -m "Undid feature merge"
```

Comment: If I use Git revert author it goes into VIM mode which I have no idea how to use. How can I skip VIM. The branch name is author. It was the last committed branch and has been merged and pushed to Github. Thanks!

Comment: VIM pops up to allow you to set the commit message.  [See here](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration) on how to make git use a different editor.

Answer (score 1):

You could do a `git reset`. This is fine if it was only a recent local merge.

If you already pushed the merge somewhere or you have more commits on top, this is no good idea. Instead you have to accept your merge and do a clean `git revert`. This way the history still contains the merge but the revert will undo the effect of the merge.